# How does a player character gain or lose Reputation?

Tags: d20-modern

In D20 Modern, how is a player character's starting Reputation decided? What rules govern its increase or decrease thereafter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each [Class](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/modern/smack/basicclasses.html) has a Base Reputation Bonus that acts like the Base Attack Bonus. Some [Occupations](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/modern/smack/occupations.html) affect your Reputation as do feats like [Renown](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/modern/smack/featorder.html#renown) and [Low Profile](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/modern/smack/featorder.html#lowpro).